# how long does a transfer from gdax to etherdelta take?

Tags: transactions, wallet-transfer, etherdelta

My question is about how long do I have to wait to get my transfer of ether from gdax to my ether-delta wallet?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how what you set the gas limit/ price at.

You can check what current prices are / network congestion are here: https://ethstats.net/

Setting  a higher gas price / limit increase the probably of your transaction being mined quicker

Comment: what would happen if I accidentely try to send BTC to an ETH address? and do BTC txs take over an hour from gdax?